# How to remove all inline script or html injection on Input text using JavaScript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, javascript-injection

I know this type of question might have asked many times but I am sure that this one is different than all of them.
I have a Input TextArea control on server side, I am trying to remove all inline script or html injection.
I was able to get rid of Script tags by doing this-

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btnHTML').click(function () {
                var textarea = document.getElementById("txtar1");
                var stringOfHtml = textarea.value;
                var wrappedString = '<div>' + stringOfHtml + '</div>';
                var noScript = wrappedString.replace(/script/g, "THISISNOTASCRIPTREALLY");
                var html = $(noScript);
                html.find('THISISNOTASCRIPTREALLY').remove();
                var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
                tmp.id = "tmp";
                tmp.innerHTML = html.html().replace(/THISISNOTASCRIPTREALLY/g, 'script');
                document.body.appendChild(tmp);
                alert(html.html().replace(/THISISNOTASCRIPTREALLY/g, 'script'));
            });
```

```html
<textarea id="txtar1" style="width:200px;height:100px"></textarea><br/>
<input type="button" id="btnHTML" value="Remove HTML" />
```

But my purpose is not solved, I am trying to restrict or remove all types of inline script injection. Few examples are-

```html
<div>
<table border="2">
<tr>
<td><b>ABCD</b></td>
<td onclick="javascript:alert('Hello')">
EFGH</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<div>
<table border="2">
<tr>
<td><b>Test</b></td>
<td alert('Hello')>
Success</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="1;url=http://www.test.com">
<BR SIZE="&{alert('Injected')}"> 
<DIV STYLE="background-image: url(javascript:alert('Injected'))">
```

Any help or suggestions would be very very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using inline JavaScript `<script> ... source ... </script>`, using external JavaScript files and importing them using `<script src="...">` helps to mitigate the attacks and make your website safe.
The way to do this in the modern browsers is to set the 'Content-Security-Policy' (CSP) property, either via meta attribute or headers.

you can use this [tutorial](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/disable-inline-javascript-for-security/) to get more knowlege regarding this.

Comment: Thanks @Sachintha for sharing the tutorial link with me. I have been going through this link and I agree that we can achieve by following CSP. But is it possible to implement this in IE8?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/policy-csp-internetexplorer